# How to check throttling rate in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, throttling

I am trying to throttle Kafka producer and consumer by setting producer_byte_rate and consumer_byte_rate via kafka_configs.bat.
How will I know if the throttling is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer after posting it.
Just to help others

Set path for JMX `set JMX_PATH=<port_num>`
and start kafka server

on another terminal type `jconsole` to see metrics and graphs.

Go to

> MBeans tab > kafka.server > fetch/produce

Here you will be able to see attributes like **byte-rate** and **throttle time**.
You can read more about that on
[Kafka Monitoring](http://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#monitoring)